# C++: Displaying characters

Tags: c++

I'm learning and improving my programming skills from "Think Like a programmer" book and I was asked to display this kind of pyramid.

```
########
 ######
  ####
   ##
```

I did it with this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        cout << ' ';

    for(int j = 0; j < 8 - i * 2; j++)
        cout << '#';

    cout << '\n';
}
```

But... the questions was "***Using the same rule as the shapes programs from earlier in the chapter (only
two output statements—one that outputs the hash mark and one that outputs
an end-of-line), write a program that produces the following shape:***"

I'm not sure, but is it possible to display something like this with only 2 statements and without using space character?

edit.

Thanks for an answer guys. But according to author I should do this with only `cout << '#'` and `cout << '\n'`. And here is my point, because it seems that manipulating with some methods or functions is not an option.

***Write a program that uses only two output statements, cout << "#" and cout << "\n",
to produce a pattern of hash symbols shaped like a ...***
Of Course with use of loops :P

Comment: You need to find a way to output the spaces implicitly.

Comment: It is even possible to have a single `cout` statement that outputs spaces, hashes and the end of line. ;) In other words: you need only your outer loop (`i`) and this single `cout` statement.

Comment: If you bulid one string per row, You have to use only one output statement

Comment: `#include <iostream>
int main() { while(std::cin) {}; }`

Comment: If you're going to quote the book, then you'd better show the rule used by "shapes programs from earlier in the chapter" that it references.

Comment: @paddy I edited my question with second quote, how author wants to display former shapes. However previous shapes didn't include any white spaces. That were half of square etc. The easy one. This seems impossible to do with logic of the previous.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do this without some kind of I/O manipulator (like `setw`) or explicitly writing spaces.  There are some other approaches but they boil down to the same thing...  And this book is obviously aimed at a programming level where you shouldn't be asked to do anything obscure.

Comment: Did you ask the author of the book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to this question is much simpler: author error. Those first few questions should have been worded to allow the use of a single space output as well (cout << " ";). I don't know how we all missed this in editing, and I apologize for the confusion this has caused. In general, any exercise that is intended to force the reader to go "digging" will be clear on that point.

By the way, this and other issues from the first edition are discussed in the document that can be found on my site [here](http://www.vantonspraul.com/content/think-programmer-errata). If you have further questions or problems with the book, please do contact me.

Comment: Thanks, that clears everything. Yet still, I'm confused to exercise 2.3 from the same chapter. It asks to display some kind of star-like object, but again, is it possible with one cout << " " ? I divided this problem to two parts - upper and lower, secondly making an algorithm to display 2 rows which have same value ( mid of star ) is impossible I guess.

Answer (score 10):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << setw(8-i) << string(8-i*2, '#') << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the position in a loop for every line. This combined with a 3 operand operator could solve this with two output statement.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    for(int k = 0; k <= 8-i; k++)
        cout << k<i ? ' ' : '#';

    cout << endl;
}
```

Leading space characters will be there anyway, You can not make an "empty" space instead of them.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure Is this what I want to know. I edited question to dispel confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's about the "art" of not using `cout << ' '`, but in that case there is another neat solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i, std::cout << '\n') {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8-i; ++j) {
            std::cout << (char)('#' - 3*(j<i));
        }
    }
}
```

And, another, even more obscure version that uses the ASCII representation rather than writing `' '` explicitly, using only one for-loop:

```cpp
int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 37; ++i) {
        std::cout << (char)(35-3*((i%9)<=((i-1)/9)) - 3*((i%9)>=(9-(i-1)/9)) \
            - 22*(!(i%9)) );
    }
}
```

I do not say this is good programming practice, but maybe it helps someone in realizing - again - that it's in the end all numbers and registers.

Comment: It totally depends on the author of the book. The author might mean to encourage people to look at the underlying ASCII code. Also, I cannot image that `setw` for example, does NOT use `' '` explicitly in its code somewhere down the line.

Comment: I meant that it's not correct to do math on ascii to get the code of `' '`, just use that code directly! It's not funny for that reason. That's my point.

Comment: It's clearly said you can use `<<` to output only `'#'` and `'\n'`. Your code outputs `' '` (yes, by way of some 'tricky' math, but still, it calls `operator <<` with `' '`. So the answer is completely wrong.

Comment: It's not meant to be funny and not more wrong than using `setw`, which has to have exactly the same functionality as `<< ' '`. How else would it be able to do the padding? Just because you do not see that call anymore, it doesn't mean it doesn't happen.